# JavaScript | Node.js send serverside object to client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to send a `socket.io` packet from the server to the client source code.

**My problem:**

If I code both without `socket.io` then it would work like the following: https://jsfiddle.net/v68sd1t3/

But how could i save the data packet from:

```
socket.on('init', function(data)
```

into an array to use it client side when I receive the init packet?

I've been trying to add it to a array. But it wouln't let me access the values outside of the socket.on function.

What I have tried:

```
var socket = io();
window.game = {};

socket.on('init', function(data)
{
    window.game = data;
});

console.log(game);
```

Which would return a blank object. What am I doing wrong?

**My Client code:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();

    socket.on('init', function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });

</script>
```

**My Server code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server started.');

// Modules start

var config = function() 
{
    var self = this;
    self.updateRate = 1000 / 60;
    self.roomWidth = 1920;
    self.roomHeight = 1080;
    self.playerSpeed = 4;
};

var data = function() 
{
    var self = this;
    self.loopLast = Date.now();
    self.loopNow = Date.now();
    self.loopDelta = 1;
    self.players = [];
};

var utilitys = function() 
{
    var self = this;

    self.direction = function(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    {
        return Math.atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2);
    };

    self.distance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    {
        return Math.sqrt((x2 -= x1) * x2 + (y2 -= y1) * y2);
    };

    self.nextId = function(array)
    {
        for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (!self.findBy(array, 'id', i + 1))
            {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }

        return array.length + 1;
    };
};

var mechanics = function(config, data, utilitys)
{
    var self = this;

    self.updateDelta = function()
    {
        data.loopNow = Date.now();
        data.loopDelta = (data.loopNow - data.loopLast) / config.updateRate;
        data.loopLast = data.loopNow;
    };

    self.updatePlayers = function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.players.length; i++)
        {
            data.players[i].update(i);
        }
    };

    self.gameLoop = function()
    {
        self.updateDelta();
        self.updatePlayers();
    };

    self.player = function(x, y)
    {
        this.id = utilitys.nextId(data.players);
        this.spawned = data.loopNow;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.targetX = x;
        this.targetY = y;
        this.pendingDelete = false;

        this.updateLocation = function()
        {
            if (utilitys.distance(this.x, this.y, this.targetX, this.targetY) > 20)
            {
                var direction = utilitys.direction(this.targetX, this.targetY, this.x, this.y);
                this.x += Math.cos(direction) * (config.playerSpeed * data.loopDelta);
                this.y += Math.sin(direction) * (config.playerSpeed * data.loopDelta);
            }
        };

        this.update = function(index)
        {
            this.updateLocation();

            if (this.pendingDelete)
            {
                data.players.splice(index, 1);
            }
        };
    };
};

// Modules end

// Game init start

var game = {};
game.config = new config();
game.data = new data();
game.utilitys = new utilitys();
game.mechanics = new mechanics(game.config, game.data, game.utilitys);
setInterval(game.mechanics.gameLoop, game.config.updateRate);

// Game init end

// Socket start

var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    game.data.players.push(new game.mechanics.player(game.config.roomWidth / 2, game.config.roomHeight / 2));
    socket.emit('init', game);
});

// Socket end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solution**

Try it like that:

```
socket.on('init', function(data){
    window.game = data;

    // update your game or call update method right HERE! 
    console.log(game);
});
```

### **Your Mistake**

Your problem was, that you were trying to access empty object that not been updated yet:

```
// that is just creates subscribe function
// you created listener, but it does not mean that event actual happened
socket.on('init', function(data)
{
    window.game = data;
});

// now you are trying to access data, that is not updated yet
console.log(game);
```

Actual event will appear later, and you can access this `game` object only after `function(data)` fired by socket.

**P.S.** As javascript is asynchronous `init` event listener won't be fired before all your sync expressions being processed by **event loop** *(till `console.log` in our case)*.
Only after that, whenever socket event would happen `init` listener can be fired.

---

### **My Suggestion**

I suggest you to subscribe on events with game methods. 
Some abstract game structure:

```
class Game{
    constructor(config, socket){
       super.apply(this, arguments);
       // subscribe to startup events
       // game will start automatically after init event comes
       socket.on('init', this.init);
       // save for future ;)
       this.socket = socket;
       this.config = config;
    }
    init(data){
        // subscribe to real time events
        this.socket.on('update', this.update);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.tick, this.config.updateRate);
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, false);
        window.addEventListener('resize',    this.onResize,    false);

        //some stuff
        this.update(data);
    }
    tick(){
        // recalculate some stuff each frame, then redraw
        this.draw()
    }
    draw(){
      //draw
    }
    update(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
    onMouseDown(){}
    onResize(){}
}

var game = new Game(config, socket);
```